# Can we derive this from Mertens theorem?

Tags: prime-numbers, riemann-hypothesis

*From "Elementary Methods in Number theory" by 'Melvyn B. Nathanson',*

> I know from Merten's first theorem that $\displaystyle R(x)=\sum_{p\leq x}\dfrac{\ln p}p-\ln x=O(1)$ but can it be $O\left(\dfrac{\ln^4x}{x^{1.5}}\right)$ at least for large numbers?
>
> because the thing is, I showed, $$\pi(x)-\operatorname{li}(x)=\sum_{n\leq x}a_n\operatorname{li}(n)-\sum_{n\leq x}a_n\operatorname{li}(n)\left(\operatorname{li}(n)-\dfrac n{\ln n}\right)$$ where $\operatorname{li}(x)$ is the logarithmic integral ($\operatorname{Li}(x)+1.04$) and $\sum_{n\leq x}a_n=R(x)$
>
> $\therefore a_n=O\left(\frac{\ln^4x}{x^{1.5}}\right)$ only if we consider $R(x)=\left(\tfrac{\ln^4x}{x^{1.5}}\right)$, which is my question
>
> (and also the Riemann's hypothesis).

Comment: A couple of notes which should be left off the answer : the title is a little irrelevant, since I don't see you are implying something _from_ Merten's theorem. Also, I don't see how to come up with that $\pi$-$\text{li}$ result, but I suspect it is incorrect (I have no idea how RH jumps in here). And at last, perhaps it is best to show some effort at formatting the question with $\TeX$ which we prefer here rather than images.

Comment: Off topic note on language: "imply something from a theorem" would be better said as "derive something from a theorem."

Answer (score 6):

Obviously not. Your asymptotics tend to $0$ for large $x$, whereas that $O(1)$ term in *Merten's theorem* is $\geq 1$. Precisely,

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left | \sum_{p \leq x} \frac{\log p}{p} - \log(x) \right | \approx 1.3325$$

This is usually denoted as $B_3$.

As a final note, your formulation of Merten's theorem is incorrect, and presumably you meant to take the absolute value at the difference.

Comment: Ok just take a look on https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9x-6WzCbIMISFd2S3U5bzg0MFU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The biggest issue here probably has less to do with differentiation under the summation and more to do with the fact that, in the classical sense, the Heaviside function isn't differentiable at 0; we talk about its derivative in the context of distributions.

Comment: @BalarkaSen apart from ongoing discussion, via analytic continuation when s = −1, R.zeta(-1)=1+2+3+...=-1/12 hence we could see that Ramanujan was right !